# What is the vorticity of a velocity field?

Tags: vector-analysis, rotations, fluid-dynamics, curl

If $u:\mathbb{R}^3\to \mathbb{R}^3$ is a velocity field one defines the vorticity as the curl
\begin{align}
\omega= \text{curl}(u).
\end{align}
I just read that vorticity measures the rotation of the motion. I can't imagine what the vorticity is. I computed examples as $u_1=(-y,x,0)$ and $u_2=(-y,x,z)$. For both the vorticity is $\omega=(0,0,2)$. I plotted both

[image]
[image]

For $u_1$ you can see that $(0,0,2)$ is perpendicular but how does it measure rotation? In the case of $u_2$ it is not perpendicular but also here I don't know what the vorticity has to do with rotation.

Comment: The magnitude of the vorticity vector tells you the magnitude of the rotation. The direction of the vorticity vector is normal to the plane of rotation.

Comment: @K.defaoite That's perfectly true for rigid body motion. Vorticity is the curl. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vorticity) contains some nice examples where a fluid rotates and is (paradoxically as it seems) an *irrotational vortex*. In contrast there is the parallel flow with shear that has vorticity.